# Installing my project from testpypi gives me an error

Tags: python, pypi, setup.py, python-packaging

I am learning how to package python projects and publish them and I ran into a problem I have been trying to solve ,but failed.

I have this small project and I am trying to upload it to Testpypi

I managed to upload it there and I can even find it at (https://test.pypi.org/project/cli-assistant/)

Problem: When I try to install it using

```bash
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ cli-assistant
```

I get this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cli-assistant (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for cli-assistant
```

Here is the full setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("Description.rst", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    requirements = fh.read()

setup(
 name= 'cli-assistant',
 version= '0.0.5',
 author= 'my name',
 author_email= 'my email',
 license= 'MIT License',
 description='guide you with terminal and git commands',
 long_description=long_description,
 url='https://github.com/willsketch/Helper',
 py_modules=[ 'my_helper'],
 packages= find_packages(),
 install_requires = [requirements],
 classifiers=[
    'Programming Language :: Python',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
    ],
 include_package_data=True,
 package_data={'helper':['examples.txt']},
 entry_points= {
     'console_scripts':[
         'helper = my_helper:cli',
     ]
 }
)
```

Comment: You have [uploaded](https://test.pypi.org/project/cli-assistant/0.0.5/#files) only egg file. Pip cannot install eggs. You should upload a source distribution (.tar.gz or .zip) and/or a wheel (.whl).

Comment: hey man , thanks alot ! It worked how can i accept your answer as top answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [uploaded](https://test.pypi.org/project/cli-assistant/0.0.5/#files) only an `.egg` file. Pip cannot install eggs. You should upload a source distribution (`.tar.gz` or `.zip`) and/or a wheel (`.whl`).